# Trying to find out why a Flutter GridView's loop-generated item has a wrong per-loop index

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, gridview

I am currently developing an app with Flutter and I am trying to find out, why the following is happening.

I am generating a GridView with this code:

```
GridView _generateGridView() {
    return GridView.count(
      crossAxisCount: 3,
      children: _generateChildrenList(),
    );
  }
```

The function _generateChildrenList() generates the child elements for the GridView (I simplified the code):

```
List<Widget> _generateChildrenList() {
    List<Widget> _returnWidgets = [];

    String number;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++) {

    number = "0"; /* getting a value from another function. Must be a string. */

        _returnWidgets.add(
        Padding(
            child: Material(
              child: Ink(
                child: InkWell(
                    child: Container(
                        child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
                          GestureDetector(
                            child: Hero(
                              tag: "tag_$number",
                              child: Image(...),
                            ),
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => InfoScreen(number)));
                            },
                          ),
                          /* More containers... */
                        ],)
                    ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        );
    }

    return _returnWidgets;
}
```

This generates a 3-column GridView with `numberOfElements` elements. Each element has the `onTap` function: `Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => InfoScreen(number)));`.

If - for example - `numberOfElements` contains 200 elements, this function generates 200 GridView elements with the `onTap` function shown above. I want to have it that way that the `number` in the function depends on the `number` variable set anew every loop:

For example:
When `number == "001"`, the `onTap` function should look like this: `Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => InfoScreen("001")));`

When `number == "100a"`, the `onTap` function should look like this: `Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => InfoScreen("100a")));`

Actually, when I am running the layout, it doesn't matter which element from those 200 I tap - InfoScreen is always called with the `number=200` (the last element). So it seems that the number variable of each already-added elements becomes overwritten, when the next element is being generated.

I am thinking about it quite a while and I think it's easy to solve but I actually don't get it.

Can someone help me? Maybe there is something special about Flutter's GridViews what I don't know yet?

Thank you for your time!
teha

Comment: if you add `print(number);` before `_returnWidgets.add(...` what do you see on the logs?

Comment: Then it prints 200 lines with the numbers 1, 2, 3 etc. So that seems correct.

Comment: so change for testing only: `(context) => InfoScreen(number)` to `(context){print(number); return InfoScreen(number);}` whats on the logs after tapping `GestureDetector`?

Comment: That always prints `200` when tapping an element.

Comment: `child: GridView.count(
crossAxisCount: 3,
children: generateChildren(),
),


generateChildren() {
var list = <Widget>[];
for (int i=0; i<200; i++) {
var number = 'button #$i';
print(number);
list.add(RaisedButton(
child: Text(number),
onPressed: () => print(number),
));
}
return list;
}`

Comment: Sorry, had time just now to try this. Your code is working - it prints "button #1 button #2 button #3" (each in one line) on painting and when tapping on "button #7", it prints "button #7" etc.

Comment: Wait I think I got it thanks to you and I try to understand what the problem was...

Comment: So basically, I think the problem had nothing to do with the loop itself. The problem was, that the `String number` variable was declared outside the loop, however I set it each loop. The code I posted in my question was not 100% precise, so I edited it just a minute ago. I don't understand why this created the problem. Why does the loop take the last set value of the variable when it is declared outside the loop? So far, thank you so much for the help - I was able to fix it with your code as it helped me to understand :)